# Unable to Delete/Modify files in the USB

Tags: usb

I am unable to delet/modify files on the USB. The usb cannot be formatted as it says disk is wirte protected. How do I change the settings.. I tried to do it but the usb does not allow me to change settings..Pls help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a flash drive with a hardware write-protect switch...

If you can access your flash drive's location (where the contents of it are), remember it and open up a terminal session and type `mount`. Then find your mount point (that location you remembered earlier), and check the options. If it's `ro` and NOT `rw`, you can try remounting it.

It will list stuff like this (this is a example of my output, running under a live USB setup, although the process for installed, non-live systems are very similar):

`/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)`

`/dev/sdb1 on /media/ki2ne/FLASHDRIVE type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed)`

(the rest of the mount points are cut for brevity)

I would identify `/dev/sdb1` to be the device for my flash drive (although yours might be different). So I would do `mount -t vfat -o rw,remount /dev/sdb1 /media/ki2ne/FLASHDRIVE`.